# Need a time-dependent checkbox update

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I have two formula fields that are working beautifully. The first, Child's Age, calculates (based on a child's birthdate) whether the child is under 3, between 3 and 5, and Over 5. The second, a checkbox called Active MCH, is checked if the child is under five but unchecked if the child is over 5. This all works great.

Now, though, they want to uncheck the box 30 days AFTER the child's birthdate, not on it. I thought I could just create another checkbox called Active in Program and create a workflow that unchecked it 30 days after the first checkbox is unchecked.

This does not work. I thought the problem was that I was updating the checkbox based on a formula field, so I tried creating a Text field with the value in the Child's Age field. I couldn't get this field (Child's Age(text)) to populate with the values from the Child's Age field.

How do I do this time-based workflow so the kids get 30 days grace period after their 5th birthday before they are removed from the program?

Comment: Couldnt you just set the active mch checkbox to evaluate 5 yrs plus 30 days instead of the current 5 years?

Comment: +1 gorav. The solutions below are excellent, but SteveMo and Elizabeth Davis convinced me to go with the Active MCH checkbox modification.

Answer (score 1):

Formulas don't trigger workflow rules, only active modifications to the records do. If you wanted a time-based workflow rule, you'd want to start by using real fields instead of formulas, and set them using process builder or workflow rules.

First, create your picklist (Under 3, Between 3 and 5, Over 5), and set the values using a rule (time-based delay based on birth date field). Next, create your two checkboxes, and set the Active MCH based on the picklist when it isn't blank using another rule. Last, set the Active in Program box to uncheck 30 days after Active MCH unchecks, using another rule.

In summary, you should have one picklist, two checkboxes, and three workflow rules or process builder actions.

Comment: sfcdfox: I like this time delay based on the birth date field solution. I can't quite picture it, though. Say you enter a child who is 2.5 years old. How would you get that picklist to change?

Comment: @TrishPerkins If you're using, say, the Process Builder, you can build it like a mini computer program. If birthdate is less than 3 years ago (e.g. 2.5 years), set the picklist to Under 3, with a scheduled action at 3 years after birthdate to update picklist to 3-5. Same for the other few conditions. It's a bit harder to visualize in workflow rules, because you'd end up with a few different rules to handle each scenario.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rule Criteria]

[image: Evaluation Criteria]

Your Rule criteria Should be this -

Your Evaluation criteria should be this- 
Then add a time dependent workflow action to do a field update after 30 days.

Hope this will meet your criteria.

Note# I have used Account as my object, that should be your obbject in your org.

Comment: Problem is Active MCH is a formula field. That's the problem.

Comment: Ohh, I thought it was update via trigger.